# How can I render a cell differently if the row is selected?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables plugin and would like to have a custom renderer for a cell. However I would like the cell to be shown differently if the row in the table is selected.

This is the code I have so far:

```
render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
    var rowIdx = meta.row;
    var rowSelected = ???;  // How do I determine this?
    if (rowSelected) {
        return "<i class='foo'></i>";
    }
    return "<i class='bar'></i>";
}
```

I don't know how to query the table itself from inside the renderer, to test if the row (given by meta.row) is selected. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

If you're using [Select](http://datatables.net/extensions/select/) extension, selected rows would have class `selected`.

Use the code below to dynamically render cell content when row is selected.

You also need to handle [`select`](http://datatables.net/reference/event/select) and [`deselect`](http://datatables.net/reference/event/deselect) events to redraw the row once it has been selected or deselected.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   select: true,
   columnDefs: [
      {
         targets: 0,
         render: function(data, type, full, meta){
            var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(meta.settings);
            if(type === 'display'){
               if($(api.row(meta.row).node()).hasClass('selected')){
                  data = data + ' (selected)';
               }
            }
            return data;
         }
      }
   ]
});

// Handle row selection event
$('#example').on('select.dt deselect.dt', function(e, api, type, items) {
   api.rows(items).invalidate('data').draw(false);
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/70wr28vz/1/) for code and demonstration.